# Slow login on Ubuntu 22.04 with Nvidia GPU

Tags: nvidia, login, 22.04, wayland

I am getting slow logins (5+ seconds) on my Ubuntu 22.04. All related threads on this site point to Nvidia drivers as the main suspect. I looked into `/var/log/gpu-manager-switch.log` and got this:

```
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager-switch.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic/kernel
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic/kernel/nvidia-520
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic/kernel/nvidia-515srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic/kernel/nvidia-515
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic/kernel/nvidia-510srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic/kernel/nvidia-510
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic/kernel/nvidia-470srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic/kernel/nvidia-470
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic/kernel/nvidia-450srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic/kernel/nvidia-418srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic/kernel/nvidia-390
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic/updates/dkms
Found nvidia.ko module in /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic/kernel
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? no
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? yes
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? yes
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 1002:15d8
BusID "PCI:5@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:1f91
BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
can't open /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/boot_vga
Is boot vga? no
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver.
can't open /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/boot_vga
Chassis type: "10"
Laptop detected
/etc/u-d-c-nvidia-runtimepm-override found. Will try runtimepm if the kernel supports it.
Linux 5.15 detected.
Is nvidia runtime pm supported for "0x1f91"? yes
Trying to create new file: /run/nvidia_runtimepm_supported
Checking power status in /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/0000:01:00.0/power
Error while opening /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/0000:01:00.0/power
Is nvidia runtime pm enabled for "0x1f91"? no
Found "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "amdgpu"
output 0:
    card0-eDP-1
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card0: 1
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "amdgpu"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "amdgpu"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "amdgpu"
Does it require offloading? no
last cards number = 2
Has amd? yes
Has intel? no
Has nvidia? yes
How many cards? 2
Loading nvidia with "no" parameters
Has the system changed? No
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
Takes 10000ms to wait for nvidia udev rules completed.
AMD IGP detected
NVIDIA hybrid system
can't open /sys/module/nvidia/version
Creating /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-offload.conf
Setting power control to "auto" in /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control
Trying to create new file: /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-runtimepm.conf
Loading nvidia with "no" parameters
```

Something is clearly wrong with Nvidia! but what is it and how to fix it?

I have already switched between several drivers with no positive result.

System specs:

```
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ---------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: Nitro AN515-43 V1.12 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.15.0-52-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 21 hours, 56 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2190 (dpkg), 7 (flatpak), 23 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: fish 3.5.1 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 42.4 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru-blue-dark [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru-blue [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3750H with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx (8) @ 2.300GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         GPU: AMD ATI Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           Memory: 3588MiB / 13920MiB
```

Comment: Nvidia drivers aren't being loaded and you're running with the iGPU AMD. Unless you're dual-booting with **Windows 11** you can disable Secure Boot in UEFI. That should be enough, assuming you have the correct Nvidia drivers already installed. Then, if you want to run with the Nvidia graphics instead just open Nvidia X Server Settings, select the "high performance" profile and reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ChanganAuto . disabling secure boot solved it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, any solution for Ubuntu installed in Legacy with no secure boot?

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon You can't have a functional dual-boot with Windows 11 if you install Ubuntu in Legacy mode. And doing that is simply put ridiculous more than a decade after UEFI mode has become the norm for any preinstalled Windows. Very soon it won't even be an option in the firmware and not a second too late. Now, a standalone Ubuntu in Legacy mode should not have any issue with unsigned drivers therefore your question is nonsensical.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, thank you for reply.  it's standalone Ubuntu in Legacy mode, wasn't by choice that it was installed in Legacy mode (Acer limitation). I've tried several solutions from the forum and only managed to fixed it with the installation of CUDA.  Cheers

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon If you have a specific question you're welcome to post a new question.

Comment: I have the same symptoms, but I think my problem is different. I *don't* in fact want to use the Nvidia GPU for graphics, only for compute power (ie. OpenCL). The PopOS/system76 PowerDaemon, when I tell it about this preference, does the right thing (I think) and aliases the `nvidia-drm` and `nvidia-modeset` modules to  `off` and that's why they are not loaded, and consequently the flag file in `/run` is not created when `gpu-manager` is looking for it. Left hand (Ubuntu via `gpu-manager`) doesn't know what right hand (system76 via `PowerDaemon`) is doing. How can make them cooperate? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ChanganAuto pointed out in the comments, the problem was caused by secure boot. disabling secure boot enabled the Nvidia drivers to be loaded.